# The arguments of a function gets called in different files

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

The complete testing code shown in the following

The header file ( say, a.h ) defines the following codes:

```
typedef uint8_t EnrollT(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void ChangeT(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *, ChangeT *);
```

In one of my c ( say, test1.c) files which includes a.h shown below:

```
void Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2){
     printf("Happy Enrolling");
}

void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2){
     printf("Happy Changing");
}

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q)
{
    p = Enroll;
    q = Change;

    return something;
}
```

Above codes gets compiled okay, however, in the following code, I am a little bit confused in the another c file ( say, test2.c ) which includes a.h as well.

```
void priTest(){
    somethingOkay = ClientAlloc( ???? );
}
```

In this case, what arguments should I add in my ClientAlloc() function in test2.c ?

---

@dasblinkenlight

To be clear, I've modified the code as shown in the following:

In the header

```
typedef uint8_t EnrollT(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void ChangeT(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *, ChangeT *);
```

In test1.c

```
void Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2){
     printf("Happy Enrolling");
}

void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2){
     printf("Happy Changing");
}

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q)
{
    p = Enroll;
    q = Change;

    return something;
}
```

In test2.c

```
uint8_t Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);


void priTest(){
    somethingOkay = ClientAlloc( Enroll, Change );
}
```

---

@Joachim Pileborg

I modifed my code as shown in the following, please let me know if I misunderstand what you mean in your reply.

In my header a.h

```
typedef uint8_t (*EnrollT)(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void (*ChangeT)(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *, ChangeT *);
```

In test1.c

```
void Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2){
     printf("Happy Enrolling");
}

void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2){
     printf("Happy Changing");
}

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q)
{
    *p = Enroll;
    *q = Change;

    return something;
}
```

In test2.c

```
EntrollT enroll;
ChangeT  change;

void priTest(){
    somethingOkay = ClientAlloc( &enroll, &change );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Enroll` and `Change` to make an `EnrollT` and `ChangeT` function pointers, because they are incompatible. In order for the functions to match, they must have the same signatures as the functions declared in your `typedef`s:

```
uint8_t Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2){
    printf("Happy Enrolling");
    return 0;
}
void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2){
     printf("Happy Changing");
}
```

Now you can pass these functions to `ClientAlloc`:

```
somethingOkay = ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change);
```

Since the call happens in a different file, you need to forward-declare your functions at the top of the file:

```
uint8_t Enroll(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
void Change(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);
```

Comment: @user3815726 Return type is important as well - `Enroll` needs to return `uint8_t`.

Comment: the function definition should be in test1.c ( Enroll(...) and Change(...) ) and somethingOkay ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change ); and forward-declare should be put at test2.c, is this what you mean ?

Comment: @user3815726 Yes, you need forward declarations in the file from which you make the call to `ClientAlloc`. You may put them into `test1.c`'s header if you have one, or simply forward-declare them in `test2.c` if you prefer.

Comment: an error happened: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @user3815726 On what line does it happen? Did you include the first header in your `test2.c`?

Comment: yea, I did include the header. the error occurs at somethingOkay = ClientAlloc(Enroll, Change); I am still checking why this happens.

Comment: @user3815726 That's odd: you'd get an error like that if you forgot to include `a.h`, or misspelled the name of `ClientAlloc` function in the header or in the call.

Comment: @user3815726 Did you include `a.h` in `test2.c`?

Comment: please let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: I have found out the root cause and your reply is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want e.g. `EnrollT` to be a *pointer* to a function, then you need to declare it as such:

```
typedef uint8_t (*EnrollT)(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
```

Secondly, the functions definitions you use do *not* match the type-alias you create, so while it might build without *errors*, you still have problems in your code that should cause compiler *warnings*, and if you don't get warnings then you should enable more warnings when building. Warnings are often a sign of you doing something you should not do, that might lead to undefined behavior and possible crashes. And don't fix warnings by just some simple casting, try to find out the root cause of the warnings, and fix that instead.

Thirdly, and the problem you're asking about. If you make the change in the first paragraph, then it's simple:

```
EntrollT enroll;
ChangeT  change;

ClientAlloc(&enroll, &change);
```

However, that is the *simple* part, because you have to modify the `ClientAlloc` function too, to be able to handle the emulated *pass by reference* handling:

```
struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT *p, ChangeT *q)
{
    // Note use of dereference operator `*` here
    *p = Enroll;
    *q = Change;

    return something;
}
```

At least if you want to set `p` and `q` to the functions `Enroll` and `Change`, so you could call them from the code that called `ClientAlloc`. IF that's *not* what you want to do, but instead pass in functions pointer to be called by e.g. `ClientAlloc` then you need to make more modifications, like saving the pointer passed to the function instead of assigning to them.

---

If you want to pass in function pointer to be used by `ClientAlloc` instead, then you should not define the functions inside that source file, instead define them where they are supposed to be, in the source *calling* `ClientAlloc`, then you should have e.g.

Header file:

```
typedef uint8_t (*EnrollT)(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2);
typedef void (*ChangeT)(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2);

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT, ChangeT);
```

Test1.c:

```
// Declare the function pointers
// (static so the won't be exported)
static EnrollT enroll;
static ChangeT change;

struct ClusterT * ClientAlloc(EnrollT e, ChangeT c)
{
    enroll = e;
    change = c;

    ...
}
```

And finally your test2.c:

```
uint8_t my_enroll_function(uint16_t test1, uint16_t test2)
{
    ...
}

void my_change_function(uint64_t post1, uint8_t post2)
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    ClientAlloc(my_enroll_function, my_change_function);
}
```

Comment: @user3815726 But when you e.g. pass a function as argument to another function, it decays to a *pointer* to the function. In my last example code, doing it like shown is the same as doing it like `ClientAlloc(&my_enroll_function, &my_change_function);`.

Comment: If I change the code about my EnrollT and ChangeT to be a function pointer, then EntrollT enroll; ChangeT  change; should be declared in test2.c and then call somethingOkay = ClientAlloc(&enroll, &change ); ---- is this what you mean ?

Comment: @Pileborg, thanks but I got the eorror: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast. I have just updated my post, please check.

Comment: Peiborg, any thoughts?

Comment: I have found out the root cause and your reply is very useful to me.